# TraceId / SpanId is not getting printed inside flux doOnNext lambda block in webflux application with Sleuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-cloud

When a log statement is encountered inside doOnNext block of flux, traceid and spanId not getting populated. but outside of block its getting printed in webFilter. below is the WebFliter implementation in Reactive SpringBoot Application with Sleuth.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequestDecorator;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class APILoggingFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest httpRequest = exchange.getRequest();
        final String httpUrl = httpRequest.getURI().toString();

        ServerHttpRequestDecorator loggingServerHttpRequestDecorator = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
            String requestBody = "";

            @Override
            public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                log.info("Service Request URL before {}", httpUrl);
                Flux<DataBuffer> response =  super.getBody().doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                        Channels.newChannel(byteArrayOutputStream).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
                        requestBody = IOUtils.toString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8").replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(),StringUtils.EMPTY);
                        log.info(" Service Request json, {}", httpUrl, requestBody);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.info("Service Request, URL {}, {}, {}", httpUrl, requestBody, e);
                    }
                });
                log.info("Service Request URL after {}", httpUrl);
                return response;
            }
        };

        ServerHttpResponseDecorator loggingServerHttpResponseDecorator = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(exchange.getResponse()) {
            String responseBody = "";
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                Mono<DataBuffer> buffer = Mono.from(body);
                log.info("Service Response, URL {}", httpUrl);
                return super.writeWith(buffer.doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                        Channels.newChannel(byteArrayOutputStream).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
                        responseBody = IOUtils.toString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8").replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), StringUtils.EMPTY);
                        log.info("Service Response, URL {}, {}", httpUrl, responseBody);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.info("Service Response, URL {}, {}, {}", httpUrl, responseBody, e);
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(loggingServerHttpRequestDecorator).response(loggingServerHttpResponseDecorator).build());
    }

}
```

Logs Printed :

2023-06-22 22:43:40.859  INFO [emp-mgmt,4edae7c9825b4698,4edae7c9825b4698,false] 6596 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.e.p.config.APILoggingFilter          : Service Request URL before http://localhost:8083/api/v1/addEmp
2023-06-22 22:43:40.867  INFO [emp-mgmt,4edae7c9825b4698,4edae7c9825b4698,false] 6596 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.e.p.config.APILoggingFilter          : Service Request URL after http://localhost:8083/api/v1/addEmp
2023-06-22 22:43:40.935  INFO **[emp-mgmt,,,]** 6596 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.e.p.config.APILoggingFilter          :  Service Request json, http://localhost:8083/api/v1/getEmp, {
"uId":null,
"empId": "932046783773",
"empName": "Adam",
"idNumber": "860937"
}

2023-06-22 22:43:49.270  INFO [emp-mgmt,4edae7c9825b4698,4edae7c9825b4698,false] 6596 --- [     parallel-2] config.APILoggingFilter          : Service Response, URL http://localhost:8083/api/v1/addEmp
2023-06-22 22:43:49.283  INFO [emp-mgmt,4edae7c9825b4698,4edae7c9825b4698,false] 6596 --- [     parallel-2] config.APILoggingFilter          : Service Response, URL http://localhost:8083/api/v1/addEmp, {
"uId":76543467,
"empId": "932046783773",
"empName": "Adam",
"idNumber": "860937"
}

#### Log statement with "Service Request json" does not have traceId and SpanId.

Using spring-webFlux:5.1.5.RELEASE and Sleuth 2.1.0.RELEASE.
Please help.